# Create a form for dynamic models - Yii

Tags: php, forms, yii, model

I have to create a form for a set of models, but unfortunately, I don't know how to do. 
My first idea is to create a single form and a controller action which renders the view containing the form. But, this idea let me face an error. I create an action like this :

```
public function actionAddInfo($id){
    $participant = Participant::model()->find('id_participant = ' . $id);
    $info = InfoComp::model()->findAll('id_event = ' . $participant->id_event);
    // here I must save the model if submitted

    $this->render('addInfo', array('model' => $info));
}
```

In fact, the relationship in my models `Participant`, `Evenement` is below :

```
'idEvent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Evenement', 'id_event');
```

When accessing the variable `$info` in the view,

```
echo count($info);
```

I got the exception :

```
Undefined variable $info
```

This exception let me ask whether it is possible to proceed like that. I need your help. Else, can somebody suggest me another way to proceed ?

Comment: Why you accessing $info, in place of echo $model? this may help you    http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the variable with name `model` and you are trying to access it with name `$info`..

All you need to change is this:

```
$this->render('addInfo', array('info' => $info));
```